# 2 fake coins out of m coins in each of n boxes.

Tags: probability

A king’s minter keeps $mn$ coins in $n$ boxes each containing $m$ coins.
Each box contains $2$ false coins out of $m$ coins. The king suspects
the minter and randomly draws $1$ coin from each of the n boxes and
has these tested. What is the probability that the minter’s dishonest
actions go undetected?

Is the answer $[\frac {(m-2)}m]^n$?

Comment: @Henry I'm perhaps missing something. The probability of getting a false coin from one particular box $=2/m$ . The probability of not getting a false coin$=1-(2/m)$. Since there are n boxes, I multiplied the result n times.

Comment: OK: You originally wrote $(m-2/m)^n$ which I read as $\left(m-\dfrac2m\right)^N$ and is wrong.   You then edited your answer with brackets to $[(m-2)/m]^n$ which is equal to  $\left(1-\dfrac2m\right)^N$ and is correct

Comment: You could use \left( \dfrac {m-2}m\right)^n=\left( 1-\dfrac 2m\right)^n to display your formula.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your answer is correct. The probability of picking a genuine coin out of any box will be $$P_i={{m-2}\over m}$$

This probability is for each of the boxes. Since we want this to happen in all the boxes simultaneously, we multiply the probabilities.

$$P=P_1{\times}P_2{\times}P_3{\times}{\cdots}{\times}P_n$$
$$P=\left({m-2}\over m\right)^n$$